# Div has a margin even with margin:0 and padding:0;

Tags: css, html

I have four divs on my webpage; a header, menu, content and footer. In IE, everything displays correctly nested, but in Chrome there is a small gap between the footer and the menu and content divs. I have tried putting

```
margin:0;
padding:0;
```

on everything but there is no change. Here are some images of my problem:

In Chrome (incorrect display):

[image]

In IE (correct display):

[image]

Why is this happening? Here is my HTML:

```
<?php include "headermysql.php"?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Home</title>
<script type = "text/javascript">
function to_login_page()
{
window.location.assign("http://127.0.0.1/sxp/login.php");
}
function to_signup_page()
{
window.location.assign("http://127.0.0.1/sxp/signup.php");
}
</script>
<link rel = "stylesheet" type = "text/css" href = "textstyles.css">
</head>
<body>
<?php include "headerhtml.php";?>
<div class = "menu">
<p>menu</p>
</div>
<div class = "content">
<?php
//irrelevant PHP 
?>
<a class = "main" href = "post.php">Post new topic</a>
</div>
<div class = "footer">
<p class = "footer">Copyright Stafford King 2013</p>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

And here is my CSS:

```
.error
{
font-weight:bold;
font-family:Courier New;
color:red;
text-align:left;
font-size:20px;
margin:0;
padding:0;
}
.main
{
font-family:Courier New;
font-size:15px;
text-align:left;
color:black;
margin:0;
padding:0;
}
a.main
{
font-family:Courier New;
font-size:15px;
text-align:left;
color:#000066;
margin:0;
padding:0;
}
a.searchresult
{
font-family:Courier New;
font-size:15px;
text-align:center;
color:#000066;
margin:0;
padding:0;
}
p.footer
{
text-align:center;
font-family:Courier New;
font-size:15px;
color:#000000;
}
div.header
{
height:150px;
background-color:#008AC8;
margin:0;
padding:0;
}
div.menu
{
float:left;
width:200px;
height:800px;
background-color:#64BCE2;
margin:0;
padding:0;
}
div.content
{
height:800px;
background-color:#F9F9D9;
margin:0;
padding:0;
}
div.footer
{
height:20px;
background-color:#008AC8;
margin:0;
padding:0;
}
h2.main
{
font-family:Cambria;
font-size:35px;
color:black;
text-align:center;
margin:0;
padding:0;
}
.searchresult
{
font-family:Courier New;
font-size:15px;
text-align:center;
color:black;
margin:0;
padding:0;
}
body{margin:0;}
```

Sorry for the long post. All help is appreciated.

Comment: looks fine in chrome also http://jsfiddle.net/a4QNB/167/

Comment: Just want to ask. Why do you use `class="footer"` for the `<p>` which is already inside `<div>` with class footer? You can just set the class for div and in css use `.footer p{font-size:15px;...}` Also there is actually `<footer>` tag in HTML5 now(http://caniuse.com/#feat=html5semantic). Just saying ;)

Comment: @Sowmya works for me in JSFiddle. Why?

Comment: @Ms.Nobody i have a p.footer and a div.footer

Comment: I understand I'm just saying that u could set it even without the `class="footer"` in `<p>` html, that's all :) Btw if it works for you in fiddle but not in your pc you should try to put it on some site and send us link if it works there. I'm not sure if jsfiddle is doing some adjustments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There might be problem with the `<p>` part in footer because your footer has 20px height and font inside is 15px but the `<p>` has defaultly some margin-top and bottom I think. You should just set it to 0px;

```
p.footer
{
text-align:center;
font-family:Courier New;
font-size:15px;
color:#000000;
margin:0px;
}
```

Comment: works! thank you very much. looks like i missed that in my css. will accept answer when it lets me :)

Answer (score 0):

When i execute your sample is it also wrong in the Internet Explorer.
You can fix your problem by adding a

display: inline;

to the p.footer section

Answer (score 0):

The font always seem to cause this problem but I'm sure if you set this, it will take care of it

```
line-height: 0px;
```

Answer (score 0):

put the content in  div before footer if div before footer empty extra space showing.although you give body margin 0 padding 0 what is the reason of this if anybody know this

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31939058)

Answer (score -1):

you just need to add following css in your css file.

```
*{padding:0; margin:0;}
```

Comment: Your solution works, but I think it's a bad practice, because this reset to 0 all margins and paddings, and the OP just need to set it in `<p>`. If other user have this error, your solution could screw up all the layout...

Comment: Why is it that people keep thinking that `*{padding:0; margin:0;}` is acceptable? Unless you want literally every single element on your page to have no margin and no padding, this will just mess everything up. I give this a downvote.